# Is it possible to disable UEFI on Skylake motherboards?

Tags: motherboard, uefi

Is it possible to disable UEFI on Skylake motherboards?

Maybe a better question is: is UEFI motherboard-specific, chip-specific or both?

Comment: UEFI is the replacement to BIOS. What do you actually want to disable? EFI boot?

Comment: @Jonno I don't want to use UEFI, I want to use an ordinary BIOS.

Comment: I am willing to bet the legacy bios will be left in the dust starting with Skylake processors as are other items...http://wccftech.com/intel-skylake-remove-support-usb-based-windows-7-installation-platform-specs/

Comment: @TylerDurden - Well what you want isn't possible.  What reason do you have for wanting to use BIOS which prevents you from using larger capacity HDDs instead of UEFI which does?

Comment: Legacy BIOS has been dead for several years now (on mainstream computers).

Answer (score 3):

The motherboard manufacturer will have implemented either BIOS or UEFI, it is stored in a ROM chip on the motherboard and not tied to the chipset or CPU.

There are no boards that I know of that have a choice, it will have one or the other, and there is no 'opt-out' method. This firmware controls all of your low level devices.

BIOS is now outdated and being phased out. As such, you will likely struggle to find a board without UEFI that is compatible with Skylake processors.

Edit: After a few comments, I think you're actually referring to disabling certain UEFI components to run in a legacy mode. The UEFI is still the underlying system, but there are certain legacy components you can enable. Using the manual from [this board](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5760#manual) as an example:

- > **VGA Support**
  >
  > Allows you to select which type of operating system to
  >   boot.
  >
  > **Auto**                Enables legacy option ROM only.
  >
  > **EFI Driver**         Enables EFI option ROM. (Default)
- > **CSM Support**
  >   Enables or disables UEFI CSM (Compatibility Support Module) to support a legacy PC boot process.
  >
  > **Enabled** Enables UEFI CSM. (Default)
  >
  > **Disabled** Disables UEFI CSM and supports UEFI BIOS boot process only.
- > **Storage Boot Option Control**
  >
  > Allows you to select whether to enable the UEFI or legacy option ROM for the storage device controller.
  >
  > **Disabled**            Disables option ROM.
  >
  > **Legacy Only**         Enables legacy option ROM only. (Default)
  >
  > **UEFI Only**           Enables UEFI option ROM only.
  >
  > This item is configurable only when CSM Support is set to Enabled.

There are *components* of UEFI you can run in a traditional BIOS way, but you are *still using UEFI firmware*.

Comment: Although I am confused why you don't want to use UEFI, but that's not within the scope of the question.

Comment: Some motherboards do have a choice between uefi and legacy bios.

Comment: @Moab I did a little research before writing that and figured I'd add the qualifier 'that I know of' because I guessed there may be exceptions. Do you know of any? I'm curious how they'd work?

Comment: @Moab I was aware of the choice between UEFI and Legacy BIOS on some boards but I thought that just meant MBR booting vs EFI booting, rather than actually changing the firmware to BIOS

Comment: A couple of years ago I was buying a computer to use Linux and I had to be careful to buy a board that allowed the UEFI to be disabled because some kinds of Linux do not support it, but I thought things may have changed.

Comment: @TylerDurden I've now modified my answer as I think I now understand what you want to achieve. Just to note - UEFI is quite broadly supported now, unless you're using a distro that hasn't had much attention recently you shouldn't have too much problem leaving everything in UEFI mode rather than legacy.

Comment: @TylerDurden - Currently there are virtual no Linux distributions that are supported by the maintainers that don't support UEFI.  If you are using such distribution, that does not, you should consider the security implications of doing so

Comment: Ah, MBR, you are correct.

Comment: Embedded Linux distributions often used legacy mode bios and grub scripts... disabling UEFI in BIOS is a LOT easier. I have many boards with "OS Select". That said, some new Intel Atom tablet BIOS is UEFI only which is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of a few computers that implement EFI as a feature that's run from a BIOS (such as Gigabyte's abysmal "Hybrid EFI"), computers that support EFI-mode booting use EFI, not BIOS. Thus, there is no such thing as "switching off the EFI."

What many computers do permit is booting BIOS-mode OSes via a feature called the Compatibility Support Module (CSM). This is an add-on feature that permits an EFI to run BIOS-mode boot loaders. It's logically similar to `dosemu` or WINE under Linux, which permit Linux to run DOS or Windows programs. Importantly, when you use a CSM, the computer is still running EFI, so you haven't really gotten rid of anything EFI-related; you've just pushed it out of the way. If you simply need to run an old EFI-unaware OS, this is probably fine. If you're philosophically opposed to EFI, this won't do any good. If you want to run Windows, Linux, or some other EFI-aware OS in BIOS mode, the CSM will do the job, but the question then becomes: Why do you want to boot in the old way? There are few or no practical advantages to booting an OS that supports both boot modes via a CSM, and doing so adds complication to the boot path, so doing it this way is likely to create new problems.

Whether you like it or not, EFI is the future of computers, at least for the next few years. If you want a true old-school BIOS, you pretty much have to stick with an older computer. There is one possible workaround, though: You can use [CoreBoot,](https://www.coreboot.org/) which is an open source minimalistic firmware for *some* computers. CoreBoot is useful only when paired with one of several *payloads,* which are tools that rely on CoreBoot's basic hardware-initialization code. There is a payload that implements a BIOS, so you can use install CoreBoot plus its BIOS payload to get back to the old-fashioned way of working. (There's also a UEFI payload, if you want to go with something more modern without whatever stuff the computer manufacturer has added to its EFI.) CoreBoot itself is tiny (more like the hardware-initialization part of BIOS than like EFI), so using CoreBoot in this way is different from using an EFI plus its CSM.

The trouble with CoreBoot is twofold. First, it's developed with a limited set of computers. It can be made to work with more, but if you don't want to take a gamble on it working (possibly bricking your computer if it fails), you must pick your computer from the limited list of supported models, many of which are older. I haven't checked, but I doubt if CoreBoot yet supports any Skylake boards, although it might in the future. Second, installing CoreBoot is a highly technical task; it's not a point-and-click operation like installing the average program. If an installation fails, the firmware may have to be repaired by physically removing the chip on which it's stored, so there's significant risk, particularly if you're not comfortable with such tasks. Between these two factors, you have to be pretty dedicated to use CoreBoot.